# Best caching technique for web page caching

Tags: java, caching, web-applications

I have a webapplication in which the header for all pages is a static content. Some times for signed in users, the header may change.

What is the best caching technique to implement here to cache the header.jsp alone?

Can any one suggest pls?

Comment: Are you using any framework ??You want to cache or don't want to cache?You said it must change for signed users,But with cache it won't happen.Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I wanted the header to be cached. We are using spring framework.

Comment: for every 60 minutes the cache should be refreshed..

Comment: So you are included header.jsp  in someX.jsp right ??

Comment: No possible to refresh alone header.jsp..you have 2 options, one is refresh whole doc with meta tag or as you may that **AJAX**.

Comment: The header.jsp is completely java code...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34985/discussion-between-suresh-atta-and-phanimadhavi-vasantala)

Comment: URL url = new URL(strHeaderURL);
   URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   //connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
   //connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
   InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();  
   input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
   strContent = new StringWriter();  
   while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {     
    strContent.write( strLine+"\n" );    out.println(strContent.toString());

Comment: cannot chat..im in office...the url is blocked :(

Comment: Not possible,You definitely need a AJAX  request If you want to change/request  some portion on your document.Or you need to refresh the whole doc.

Comment: And on the top I'm assuming you know the life cycle of Jsp?? :)

Comment: :) yes. I have to achieve this some how :( . So definitely there's no other alternative? I saw some Ehcache, JCS etc.. but no knowing the real time implementation.. Very new in this area.

Comment: Sorry madhavi,I'm not aware of  those tech.And First time I'm listening to them :)

Comment: oh..k anyways thanks for ur time..

Comment: No issues,You are welcome.Good luck.